# Remove all settings from viewcontroller when dismissed

Tags: objective-c

I got multiple viewcontrollers in my project. The first viewcontroller is called when the application starts and it presents a login screen. When the credentials are correct and the user logs in, the modalview is dismissed. and another viewcontroller is instantiated like this:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
Form *formcontroller = [[Form alloc] init];
[self presentModalViewController:formcontroller animated:YES];
```

When my other viewcontroller is presented the old one disappears. On the top of my secondviewcontroller i got an logout button, wich does exactly the same, so it dismisses the current viewcontroller and calls another like this:

```
-(IBAction)logOut:(id)sender{
    [self dissmissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

And in my viewdiddisappear:

```
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    Postform3ViewController *logincontroller = [[Postform3ViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentModalViewController:logincontroller animated:YES];
}
```

The problem is:
When i push the logout button, and i return back to the logincontroller. The Credentials are still filled in. So my conclusion is that the first viewcontroller stays in memory. What am i doing wrong?

Edit:

I did find my own solution. I was profiling my application, and couldn't find any memory leaks. So i decided everything is released. Then i thought that i was able to set everything to empty myself. I did that in the viewDidAppear method like this:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  gebruikersnaam.text = @"";
  wachtwoord.text = @"";
  [self.activeTextField resignFirstResponder];
  [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all when you are using `presentModalViewController` and `pushViewController` the VC is retained so you should always release it after you have presented or pushed it.

Secondly in the third block of code it looks like you are creating a logincontroller but presenting a formcontroller. Perhaps you want to be presenting the VC you had just created:

`[self presentModalViewController:logincontroller animated:animated];`

Edit 0: For your code, in the first block, release like this:

`Form *formcontroller = [[Form alloc] init];`

[self presentModalViewController:formcontroller animated:YES];

...

[self dismissModalViewController:formcontroller animated:YES];

[formcontroller release];

Comment: It is correct that i am creating a logincontroller in the third block. My first controller is just called PostForm3ViewController.

I tried to release the controllers, but it didn't help.

Comment: Right, but you are pushing the controller "formcontroller" rather than "logincontroller" which is what you just created.

Comment: Ahh how dumb of me.. I typed it over. In my code, it is working well.. So that leaves the first question. Where should i release the controllers and how? I also edited my code.

Comment: Always follow the pattern with pushViewController/presentModalViewController where you: 1 Alloc + init, 2 Push/present, 3 release immediately

Comment: If i am releasing it directly after presenting it, the application crashes when i am presenting the viewcontroller that is called. If i remove the [formcontroller release] and the [logincontroller release]. It doesn't crash. So i must be releasing it somewhere else, except i don't know where..

Comment: I stand corrected - for presentModalViewController you should release *after* you dismiss. For pushViewController, you can release right away. The more you know!